# Maximal twist in braid group product

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Suppose I have the $s_i$ and $s^{-1}_i$ as generators, satisfying the braid relations. I call the $s_i$ "right twists" and their inverses "left twists".

Any element $w$ in the braid group can be written as a product of generators (but not in a unique way). Suppose this representation is reduced, meaning that the number of elements in this product is minimized.
Let $rt(w)$ be the maximal exponent of an element $s_i$
in all possible products representing $w$. 
Think of this as the maximal right-twisting of two strands.
Similarly, $lt(w)$ is the maximal exponent of an $s^{-1}_i$.

Now, let $R$ be a product of right twists, meaning it is a product of entries in $\{s_i\}$ but not inverses of these,
and let $L$ be a product of left twists.
Now let $RL$ be the product of $L$ and $R$.

**I want to prove that $rt(R) \geq rt(RL)$
or equivalently, $lt(L) \geq lt(RL)$.**

In other words, adding left twists to a braid cannot increase the maximal right twist.

A reference would be superb! This is not a homework problem, but for my research but it seems so simple that there should be an easy proof.

Comment: Did you mean the last inequality to be $lt(L)\geq lt(RL)$?

Comment: Hmm, this seems like it should be fairly straightforward by induction on the length of one of them.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Yes, that's what the next sentence says: its enough to show that a left-twist does not increase the maximal right-twist number..

Comment: So it seems like this reduces to something of the form $ws_{i+1}s_i$ multiplied by $s_{i+1}^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234014/braid-group-can-a-left-twist-increase-the-number-of-right-twists), I cross-posted on MO due to the lack of interest here.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. For example, for $R=s_1^2 s_2^2 s_1$ we have $C(1,2)=3$, but I think that $rt(R)=2$.